# Cesium and GeoServer WMS heatmap

Tags: javascript, wms, heat-map, cesium

I've got problem with a WMS heatmap layer in cesium. I know how to handle it in OpenLayers (single tile) and in Leaflet (non tiled plugin) but I don't know how to handle it on 3D globe.

[image]

Here is my example code

```
    const imageryLayers = this.viewer.imageryLayers;
    imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(
        new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
          url: "http://localhost:8084/geoserver/test/wms/",
          layers: "points2",
          parameters: {
            service: 'WMS',
            version: '1.3.0',
            transparent: true,
            format: "image/png",
          },
        })
    );
```

Comment: What if you use tileWidth and tileHeight parameters to increase the size of the tile requested

Comment: I tested it, still looks bad. It's about single tile handler.  But i don't know how to use it in cesium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HeatMap is a rendering transformation, but it's also a WPS process.
So go to the WPS, call the Heatmap on your data, download the resulting GeoTIFF, possibly add overviews into it, and then add it back to GeoServer as a static raster layer.